# Taking multiple image as input in tensorflowJS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I am doing text detection using tensorflow.js and have successfully implemented it with a single image, now I want to upload multiple images, convert them to tensors and predict simultaneously

This is how my Html file looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Text Detector</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="container mt-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class = "progress progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated mb-2">Loading Model</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <input id="image-selector" class="form-control border-0" type="file", multiple="multiple">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <button id="predict-button" class="btn btn-dark float-end">Predict</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h2 class="ml-3">Predictions</h2>
                        <ol id="prediction-list"></ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h2 class="ml-3">Image</h2>
                        <img id="selected-image" class="ml-3" src="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"></script>
    <script src="predictEastNew.js"></script>
</html>
```

And This is my JS file

```
$("#image-selector").change(function () {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        let dataURL = reader.result;
        $("#selected-image").attr("src", dataURL);
        $("#prediction-list").empty();
    }
    let file = $("#image-selector").prop("files")[0];
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

//let model;
//(async function () {
//    model = await tf.loadLayersModel("http://localhost:81/tfjs-model/mnist/model.json");
//    $(".progress-bar").hide();
    
//})();

async function loadModel() {

    class L2 {

        static className = 'L2';
    
        constructor(config) {
           return tf.regularizers.l1l2(config)
        }
    }
    tf.serialization.registerClass(L2);

    console.log("model loading..");
  
    // clear the model variable
    model = undefined;
    
    // load the model using a HTTPS request (where you have stored your model files)
    model = await tf.loadGraphModel("http://localhost:81/tfjs-model/east_converted/model.json");   

    $(".progress-bar").hide();
    console.log("model loaded..");
  }
  
  loadModel();

    // predict button operation
    $("#predict-button").click(async function () {
        let image = $("#selected-image").get(0);
        let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image)
            .resizeNearestNeighbor([640, 320])
            .expandDims(0);
            

    tensor = tf.cast(tensor, 'float32')
    const [output1, output2] = await model.predict(tensor);
    const data1 = await output1.data();
    const data2 = await output2.data();
    //console.log(data1)
    //console.log(data2)
    arr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < 12800; i += 1) {
        if (data2[i] > 0.6) {
            arr.push(data2[i])
        } else {
            console.log("Less than 0.6")
        }
    }
    console.log(arr)
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        console.log("Text Not Present");
        res1 = "SUCCESSFUL";
        document.getElementById('prediction-list').innerHTML = res1;
    } else {
        console.log("Text Present");
        res = "This Image cannot be Processed Becasue of superimposed Text!!!!";
        document.getElementById('prediction-list').innerHTML = res;
    }
    
});
```

Can anyone please suggest what are the changes that i need to do so than i can take multiple image as input and then do a prediction on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note this is only possible if model itself support batched operations
You can see that if looking at `model.input.shape`, is the first param `1` (fixed) or `-1` (variable)

Anyhow, lets assume model supports batched operations...

In your code you have

```js
let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image)
  .resizeNearestNeighbor([640, 320])
  .expandDims(0);
```

So your `tensor.shape` is `[1, 640, 320, 3]`

First part creates RGB tensor, second line resizes it and third line adds a batch dimension with size 1

If you had multiple images, that number would be batch size - e.g. number of images

So something like this:

```js
const tensor1 = tf.browser.fromPixels(image1).resizeNearestNeighbor([640, 320])
const tensor2 = tf.browser.fromPixels(image2).resizeNearestNeighbor([640, 320])
const tensor = tf.stack([tensor1, tensor2]); // stack images into single tensor
```

so `tensor.shape` is now `[2, 640, 320, 3]`

Comment: Thanks, @Vladimir for answering this question. And, yeah the first parameter is fixed i.e. 1. I was thinking like is it possible that I can take multiple images from the front end and loop through it and get a prediction of each image simulteniously. In that way, i will be sending only one image at a time to my model.